# Effects of Mexican Earthquake in San Andreas Fault Line

Tags: earthquakes, seismology, plate-tectonics, seismic, seismic-hazards

Could the recent 8.1 Magnitude Earthquake at the Cocos and Nazca plates off the Mexican coast have a knock on effect to the Pacific and Juan de Fuca Plates further north at the San Andreas Fault Line?

Comment: [Can an earthquake occurring within two plates trigger another earthquake in a far away plate boundary?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4964/can-an-earthquake-occurring-within-two-plates-trigger-another-earthquake-in-a-fa?rq=1)